# Optimizing Resizing Image

Tags: c#, fiddler

Hopefully this is a valid question. I know my way around C#, but I'm definitely not the best at efficient code. I'm running Fiddler on a server as a proxy server to resize images. This basically blurs out all images on a mobile device.

Is there any way to use PNG as the format and do this in a more efficient way? Or at least have a good way of testing this with large amounts of data so I can make it more efficient?

```
var oStream = new MemoryStream(oSession.responseBodyBytes);
var oBMP = new Bitmap(oStream);
oStream.Dispose();

var height = oBMP.Height;
var width = oBMP.Width;
oBMP = (Bitmap)oBMP.GetThumbnailImage(15, 15, null, IntPtr.Zero);
oBMP = (Bitmap)oBMP.GetThumbnailImage(width, height,null, IntPtr.Zero);

var oNewStream = new MemoryStream();

oBMP.Save(oNewStream, ImageFormat.Png);
oBMP.Dispose();

oSession.responseBodyBytes = oNewStream.GetBuffer();
oNewStream.Dispose();
oSession.oResponse.headers["Content-Length"] = oSession.responseBodyBytes.Length.ToString();
oSession.oResponse.headers["Content-Type"] = "image/png";
oSession.oResponse.headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache";
```

**TL;DR What is the least processor-intensive way to blur images heavily in C#?**

Comment: What does "do this in a more efficient way" mean to you?

Comment: Never call `Dispose` directly, use a `using` statement.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you're calling oBMP.GetThumbnailImage twice. Looks like it's being resized to 15, 15 then back to the original width and height.

Comment: @pmcilreavy That confused me as well, but that must be their method to "basically blur(s) out all images": shrink the image down until all detail is lost, then scale it back up.

Comment: @AluanHaddad Why "never"? What is your approach to situations where a `using` statement is impossible?

Comment: @john true, I was being overzealous. In most cases, like this one, use `using`

Comment: @Enigmativity Sorry, this is my first post and I'm confused about how to even properly phrase my question. I'm trying to efficiently blur images, and I'm assuming the way I do it (sizing all to 15x15 and then back to original) is inefficient for my server to run thousands of times. I'll edit the post with a tldr

Comment: @BobDennis - Don't assume. Measure it. Run your code and see if the performance is acceptable. If not, then try to improve efficiency.

Comment: @BobDennis - "What is the least processor-intensive way to blur images heavily in C#?" - who knows? We might give you suggestions, but you won't know the least processor-intensive way until you have two programs that produce the result you specifically want **and you race them**.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I marked the linked post as the answer since I guess resizing down and back is generally accepted as efficient. But @Enigmativity I'll definitely run a few tests with stopwatches and see what I end up with. Thanks for pushing me to look into it deeper and test it myself.